# Поменять пароль для входа на страницу

Tags: битрикс

Сайт на 1с битрикс.

Есть следующая страница:
http://www.biomaster-plus.ru/for-buyers/dokumenty-kachestva/

Вход на неё сейчас доступен только по паролю админа.
Как изменить пароль для входа именно на этой странице, не меняя пароль администратора?

Comment: а нельзя сделать ограничение по группе пользователей? Создать группу пользователей у которых есть право на редактирование/просмотр странице и дать только ей доступ? Сделать это можно через панель управления в публчином разделе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, у вас есть два папки - partner (и вы хотите, чтобы в раздел сайта /parnter входили только пользователи из группы партнёры, допустим ID группы - 201) и есть папка /employees и вы хотите чтобы туда могли входить только сотрудники (допустим, ID группы 202).

Создайте в файле .access.php следующие записи:

```
$PERM["partner"]["*"]="D";
$PERM["partner"]["201"]="R";
$PERM["employees"]["*"]="D";
$PERM["employees"]["202"]="R";
```

Где-то ещё это есть в интерфейсе админки, но я не особо пользуюсь GUI битрикс, так что не помню.

И вот ещё что. Не удаляйте доступ для админ-учётки, пусть лучше имеет права на все папки. Просто ограничьте использование данной учётной записи сотрудникам, чтобы её использовали только для редких важных операций типа обновления ядра.